# SyntaxError attempting to complete Getting Started with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Linux/Ruby/Rails, so I'm trying to learn by doing the [Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) tutorial.  In section 5.7, it doesn't specifically say what to do with this line:

```
post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
```

I assume I am to put this in the routes.rb file?  I did, but then I get this when I try to GET any of the controller actions:

```
SyntaxError
/.../blog/config/routes.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end post GET /posts/:id(.:format) posts#show ^
```

Being such a newbie, I have no idea what I should do at this point.  What is the error on this line?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not put the following in the `config/routes.rb` file.

```
post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
```

This is the result of a route entry, which is what you'd put in your `routes.rb` file.  E.g.

```
get 'posts/:id', to: "posts#show"
```

Here `get` is the HTTP method, `posts/:id` is the path pattern, and the `to: "posts#show"` is the name of the controller and action.  So, when this pattern is encountered, Rails is going to execute `show` action in `PostsController`.

Recommend a read on "[Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)".